# how can we know if the plugins are properly loaded in ionic (one-signal-cordova-plugin)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Is there a way to know if the plugin has properly loaded in ionic app which can be known right from the get go. i.e. when the ionic.run is executed.
E.g:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {    

    if (typeof window.plugins.onesignal-cordova-plugin !== 'undefined'){
      alert('it is working');
       // plugin is available
    }

}
```

as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/one-signal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/blob/master/www/OneSignal.js) I think you can test if [one-signal-cordova-plugin](https://github.com/one-signal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK) is loaded with:

```
if (window.plugins.OneSignal) { ...
```

Obviously it is always inside `$ionicPlatform.ready()`.

Comment: i had already worked it out after posting the question, sorry for being late to tick it correct. Thanks for your answer.